# Set target of page/Nested pages

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to find out if jQuery Mobile is useful for building a big single page JS application. It seems jQuery Mobile is limited in its abilities, or I am not doing it the jQuery Mobile way. If someone could clarify the following questions:

1) Is is possible to set a specific element as the target of a page? It seems that currently it will always replace the content of the body-tag.

2) Can you somehow nest pages? Is it possible to navigate between "sub" pages inside a page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but I know you can add sub pages to JQuery Mobile pages through [this project](https://github.com/ToddThomson/jQuery-Mobile-Subpage-Widget).